# Change Position Camera View on MapView Android Studio by Clicking list item on List View

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, latitude-longitude, android-mapview

So I have listview in Android studio, how can I put intent on each list item on listview to open the mapview but also change the camera position on the Map View with the latitude and longitude values that I define myself? so each item in the list view has its own Latitude and Longitude values and when we click it will show different camera position for every item list on mapview

[listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUmJI.png)

[mapview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5dYH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KSZn.png)

this my adapter class

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Jarak> jarakItems;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Jarak> jarakItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.jarakItems = jarakItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return jarakItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return jarakItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

   if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gambar);
    TextView nama = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nama);
    TextView jarak = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.jarak);

    Jarak j = jarakItems.get(position);

    //thumbNail.setImageUrl(j.getGambar(), imageLoader);
    nama.setText(j.getNama());
    jarak.setText(j.getJarak()+" Km");

    return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: quite an easy task, pass the latLang in a bundle to the MapActivity on listitem click, and then animate the camera to the new latLang

Comment: i'm sorry where i put code to animate the camera to the new latLang? May you explain more detail your answer?

Comment: how are you getting the latLang from a list item?Can you show the code

Comment: sure, you can see below, thats my code for getting the latLang from a list item

Comment: Can you also post your adapter class, this time edit your question and post it there.

Comment: of course, wait i'll do it

Comment: done, please check it

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void callListVolley(double latitude_Reseller, double longitude_Reseller) {
    itemList.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    swipe.setRefreshing(true);

    JsonArrayRequest jArr = new JsonArrayRequest(url + latitude_Reseller + "&lng=" + longitude_Reseller,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.e(TAG, response.toString());

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Jarak j = new Jarak();
                            j.setNama(obj.getString("nama_Reseller"));

                            double jarak = Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("jarak"));

                            j.setJarak("" + round(jarak, 2));

                            itemList.add(j);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // memberitahu adapter jika ada perubahan data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    swipe.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    // menambah permintaan ke queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jArr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the click item value by this code in your Activity OnCreate override merthod

```
    ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        Log.i("Hello!", "Y u no see me?");

    }

});
```

then get the lat long value from the click item and then for moving camera to that particular lat long position inside your OnMapReady method just right this code

```
     ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

           flote lat = latlong; //get this from your arraylist by putting the value position
flote long = latlong; //get this from your arraylist by putting the value position
Latlong newpos = new Latlong(lat,long);
//for create a marker on that point
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
options.position(newpos);
 mMap.addMarker(options);

//mMap is the object of google map
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                                    .newCameraPosition
                                                            (new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                                                    .target(newPos)
                                                                    .zoom(55.5f)
                                                                    .build()));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all get the `lat` and `lang` from the list item, and pass it to the intent as extras like,

> MainActivity

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            double lat = view.getLat();
            double lang = view.getLang();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putDouble("LAT", lat);
            bundle.putDouble("LANG", lang);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And then in the maps activity get that intent and animate the camera to the new point.

> MapsActivity

```
//...
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ///....

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    double lat =  bundle.getDouble("LAT");
    double lang =  bundle.getDouble("LANG");

    latLng = new LatLng(lat, lang);

}

 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    mMap = googleMap;

    CameraUpdate location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            latLng, 15);
    mMap.animateCamera(location);

}
```

Comment: but I already have the onmapready method for my current location ... does that mean I don't need to write it again?